# margin-bottom on my foreach does not align because of multiple lines due to the title length

Tags: css, for-loop, foreach, alignment, margin

[image: 1]

Above is my for each result. but on each one the title length is different hence others have more lines. My problem is my css id has `margin-bottom:50px;` on all of them but it's annoyingly not all have the same height. How do I change my css so all will be the same margin regardless of the length of my title?

```
foreach($results_n as $res_n){
    echo'<div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="" class="mb-3" alt="news banner">
            <p id="news-category">'.$res_f->category.'</p>
            <h2 id="news-title">'.$res_n->title.'</h2>
            <hr>
            <div class="row mt-1">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                    <p id="news-date" class="float-left">'.$res_n->date.'</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <p id="read-more">READ MORE</p>
                </div>
                </div>
         </div>'; }
             
    echo'</div>';
```

my css in question is:

```
#news-title {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size:15px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Seems you are using bootstrap ? You should give a try with css Flexboxes. They'll automatically manage the size for you so they are equal.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add max-height with over flow hidden.

```
#news-title {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size:15px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  max-height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```